# How to insert lines after specific string with `:` and `=`?

Tags: awk, sed

`a.txt` has only one long string as example:

```
echo 'stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu1:LOGEMU' >a.txt
```

I would like insert 2 lines after string `stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu1:LOGEMU` in `a.txt` as below :

```
~$ cat a.txt
    stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu1:LOGEMU
#insert after above string
    stack=log2:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu2:LOGEMU
    stack=log3:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu3:LOGEMU
```

I tried

```
sed '/stack\=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu1:LOGEMU/a stack=log2:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu2:LOGEMU' a.txt
```

but failed.

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you please do mention on where to insert the line, if you could elaborate on condition part more it will make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to append 2 lines to `a.txt` no matter what it contains (and you're telling us it only contains 1 line, the target line) or are you trying to append 2 lines after the target line wherever that target line appears in `a.txt`? Please [edit] your question provide more truly representative sample input/output that unambiguously demonstrates your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. If `a.txt` only has 1 line and you want to add those 2 other lines to that file then all you need is:

```
cat <<! >> a.txt
stack=log2:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu2:LOGEMU
stack=log3:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu3:LOGEMU
!
```

Otherwise if `a.txt` is a multi-line file and you want to add 2 lines after your target line no matter where it appears in that file then:

```
awk '
{ print }
$0 == "stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu1:LOGEMU" {
    print "stack=log2:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu2:LOGEMU"
    print "stack=log3:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu3:LOGEMU"
}
' a.txt
```

To update `a.txt` if you have GNU awk use `awk -i inplace 'script' a.txt`, or with any awk `tmp=$(mktemp) && awk 'script' a.txt > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" a.txt`.

Comment: I tried method with multi lines,it seemed not workable when `sudo awk '
{ print }...`.

Comment: It's workable just fine. If you have a specific problem please tell me some symptoms so I can help.

Comment: When `sudo awk ' { print }...'a.txt`,just print the output,`a.txt` has no any change.

Comment: How about without the `sudo`? Maybe you have DOS line endings (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)? Maybe you have white space at the end of lines? As you can see in my answer when you run the script I posted against the input file you posted it does produce the expected output you posted so if it's not doing the same for you then either a) you copy/pasted the script incorrectly or b) the input file you're running it against is different in some way from the input file you posted?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```sh
sed -i.bak '/^stack=log1:/r b.txt' a.txt

cat a.txt

stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu1:LOGEMU
stack=log2:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu2:LOGEMU
stack=log3:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu3:LOGEMU
```

Where you have:

```sh
cat b.txt

stack=log2:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu2:LOGEMU
stack=log3:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu3:LOGEMU
```

**Details:**

- `/^stack=log1:/`: Search for string `stack=log1:` at the start a line
- `r b.txt`: Insert content from file `b.txt` after the match

Comment: It's a good solution,just need to create another file.

Answer (score 2):

Insert two lines after a match should work:

```
sed -i '/^stack=log1/a \
stack=log2:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu2:LOGEMU \
stack=log3:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu3:LOGEMU' a.txt
```

Comment: When `sudo`,just print output,file has no change.

Comment: @kittygirl use `-i` option see my edit please.

Comment: That usage of `-i` without a backup file is specific to GNU sed. If the OP is using another sed then it won't behave as desired even if it has a `-i` option (e.g. MacOS sed).